# C 'for' loop continuing even when condition is not met

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a simple function in C that calculates days between two given dates.

It works well when both dates are valid.
When a date is not valid I set the date to "0/0/0".

This is one my `for` loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < date2.month - 1; i++)
    d2Days += monthDays[i];
```

Supposedly if a date is invalid the `date2.month` would be equal to 0 and the loop would not iterate at all but it does and it keeps on going indefinitely until `i` surpasses the size of the array and it seg faults.

[image]

You can see there `i` = 13 even when the month = 0

Can someone explain why is that such behavior?

Comment: is `date2.month` unsigned? you would be comparing `i` with `4<billions_something>`

Comment: ah yes! my Date struct is all unsigned int... didn't think of it, thanks @pmg

Comment: my compiler warns about that: `gcc ... -Wsign-compare ...` or, more generally, `gcc ... -Wextra ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think @pmg nailed it in his comment above. If your `date2.month` member is unsigned, then when it is set to zero, decrementing it by one in the loop causes the integer overflow and returns `INT_MAX`. When this occurs your loop condition will evaluate to true until you exceed the bounds of `monthDays`